# Set focus to background window

Tags: windows, focus

how can i set the focus (for input) to a background window and the foreground windows still lays over it?
I use the regular Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop.
Can remember that this works years ago on fvwm2, but it is long time ago i use this featue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're after "Focus on hover" or "sloppy focus" as it's often called. If you install GNOME Tweaks, you'll find the setting under the "Windows" section. I use this myself, and prefer it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks , yes for that i search.

Comment: Please show your appreciation for this answer by "accepting" it, i.e., click the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, i dont know i must accept the answer for set it as solved. Do it now